# Как лучше передавать id сессии

Tags: json, rest, авторизация

Хочу сделать свою авторизацию на основе REST API.

Работать она будет следующим образом:
Пользователь отправляет json вида `{ login: "foo", password: "bar" }` на */login*. В ответ получает уникальный `{ session_id: "12345" }`. Далее во всех запросах, для которых нужна авторизация, я планирую подсовывать этот *session_id*.

Вопрос в том, куда лучше его подсовывать с точки зрения безопасности. Рассматриваю два варианта:

1. Json ключом в тело запроса (тут возникает вопрос, что в этом случае  делать с GET запросами)
2. В заголовок HTTP запроса

Чем сложнее завладеть злоумышленнику, телом или заголовком? Или может быть есть другие варианты?

P.S. Куки или сторонние механизмы вроде basic auth, oauth, etc - не рассматриваю.

Comment: Я полагаю, что в  речь про https запросы. И тогда вопрос "что сложнее" становится неважным - все одинаково сложно, а с практической точки зрения - eavesdropping невозможен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробую ответить на ваши вопросы.

> Чем сложнее завладеть злоумышленнику, телом или заголовком?

По сути это один запрос и заголовок и тело находится вместе. Если "злоумышленник" добрался до заголовков, то думаю дальше труда особого не вижу.

> Или может быть есть другие варианты?

Ну собственно, сколько вариантов передачи параметров серверу вы знаете? еще один это в в самом пути URL.

К вопросу лучше хуже. У каждого способа есть свои преимущества собственно как и недостатки. Всё зависит от задач, способов отправки несколько не для того чтобы один сделать хуже другого